# Do we lose solutions dividing trig expressions? For instance, when going from $\sin3x=\sqrt{3}\cos3x$ to $\tan3x=\sqrt{3}$

Tags: trigonometry

> I was told solutions are lost when dividing trig expressions by another trig expression.

For instance, consider this problem:

> Solve
>   $$\sin 3x = \sqrt{3} \cos 3x$$ 
>   for $x$ in the range $0\leq x\leq \pi$.

In this case, surely we will lose any solutions when we divide both sides by $\cos3x$ to solve as follows:

$$\frac{\sin3x}{\cos3x} = \sqrt{3}$$

$$\tan3x = \sqrt{3}$$

$$3x:\; \pi/3, 4\pi/3, 7\pi/3$$
$$x:\; \pi/9, 4\pi/9, 7\pi/9$$

> If not, then why not?

Comment: The solutions are $$x=\frac{\pi}{9},x=\frac{4\pi}{9},x=\frac{7\pi}{9}$$

Comment: I think besides dividing, it is good to use factorization. For example: $\sin 3x=\sqrt{3}\cos 3x$ can be changed to $\cos 3x\left(\tan 3x-\sqrt{3}\right)=0$ by LHS-RHS=0 and then factorize

Comment: However, be careful that you need to check the solution whether it may have some solutions are errors

Comment: sine and cosine of the same angle are never both zero, so you don't lose any solution by dividing here.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no** problem re. losing solutions when dividing two expressions, trigonometrical or otherwise, if you bear in mind the following:-

You are probably thinking of the issues which arise if (after dividing) you wish to cancel common factors of the numerator and denominator.

For example, suppose $\sin x \cos x=\sin x$, then $\frac{\sin x \cos x}{\sin x}=1$. However, this depends upon $\sin x$ being non-zero.

So, when solving $\frac{\sin x \cos x}{\sin x}=1$ you need to be careful and say:-

Either $\sin x=0$ or $\cos x =1$.

**Re. your equation**

It is easy to see that $\cos 3x =0$ has no relevant solutions so you can divide by it without worrying.

Comment: Why is this sinxcosx/sinx=1 ,  that sinx=0  ,I understand sinx(cosx-1)=0 then sinx=0 but I do not understand how this is the same as sinxcosx/sinx=1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to perform any divisions. Since LHS of your equation (rearranged) $$\sin 3x-\sqrt 3\cos 3x=0$$ contains trigonometric functions of the same argument, you may express it as a single sine or cosine, so that you now have some expression of the form $$R\sin(3x+\psi)$$ on LHS, where $R\ne 0$ and $\psi$ are determined from what we know.

Then you have an equation of the form $$\sin z=0,$$ which is easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

So you will learn something new today.
Not in just trigonometric equation but any kind of equation if you cancel out factor you will loose solution. Let me explain with you a very simple example

- x² = x
- x²/x = 1

  - x = 1 
    Here you got only one solution, because you cancelled out one factor.
    But you can clearly see that 0 also satisfies the given equation.
    So there are two solution 0,1
    And you got only 1 because you cancelled out 1 factor.
    Same while solving trigonometric equation don't cancel out factor.